# Setting up account to upload to a website subdirectory

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, chroot

I need to setup a stfp account on Ubuntu 18.04 that meets the following requirement:

- Can upload to subfolder of website i.e. example.com/subfolder/
- Uploaded files belong to www-data group so are visible to nginx
- User cannot see outside of the given directory

I did some research and found that what I needed was a Chroot.

So I tried this:

```
adduser --home /var/www/mysite/uploadfolder --no-create-home myusers
usermod -aG www-data myusers
chmod 2770 /var/www/mysite/uploadfolder/
chmod -R g+w /var/www/mysite/uploadfolder/
setfacl -m g:www-data:rwx /var/www/mysite/uploadfolder/
```

Then I added this to sshd_config:

```
Match User mvpdocs
  ChrootDirectory /var/www/mysite/uploadfolder/
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
```

But this doesn't work.  I did some research and OpenSSH wont allow it because the Chroot folder must be owned by root and not be group writable.  If I switch the path to a root owned folder in /home directory then it works fine but I need user to upload to the sub directory.

How do I get around this issue?  Can I symlink the directory and declare the symlinked directory as part of the Chroot?  I saw mention this is possible but no examples.

What is easiest way for me to achieve a simple sftp account uploading to subdirectory of website?

**EDIT:**

I used `mount --bind /var/www/mysite/uploadfolder/ /home/user/docs/` and it worked but all the files uploaded are owned by user and has user group.

How can I make them have group www-data so can be managed by webserver and php?

Comment: are you using any kind of content management system such as wordpress or is this an entirely custom website?

Comment: yes but this directory isn't part of the wordpress install